# How to return value out of an asynchron function

Tags: fetch-api, asynccallback

I have this function to retrieve data, but I get following failure
message:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'done' of undefined.

It looks like, that the return function is not working. Would be happy
for some help. I still have my trouble with callback functions.

Thanks for your help!

```js
function getData(evt){
    fetch (evt)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json();
    });
}
getData("/getfile/xy").done(function(data){
    // do something
    console.log(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you do it with `Async` & `await` way:-

```js
async function getData(evt) {
  return await fetch (evt)
  .then (response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    return data
  })
}

// retrieve it anywahere (this must be in an 'async' function to work)
let dataRetrieved = await getData("/getfile/xy")
```

Comment: The code works fine, thank you! I have tried following: `code` setInterval(getData("/getfile/xy"), 3000); `code`. But I get a promise failure. I know, that the setInterval is also working with promise / callbacks. Do you have a suggestion, how i do get the above code working in a setInterval function?

Comment: the reason you use `setInterval` is to make sure within the **time** specified, all data successfully fetched right? If so then the above method (`async await`) will do just that even without using `setInterval`. Variable `dataRetrived` will only have data once fetching is finished.

Comment: I would like to do an update every 3 seconds. The data is fetched well in this timespan. I found out, that getData is seen as a promise and not as function. Using an anonymous function like `setInterval(function(){getData("/getfile/xy")}, 3000);``solves the problem

Comment: Yup. If it's solved your problem, then great! Setting `setInterval` to **invoke** the function that call the **fetch** for every **3 secs** will work with your code `setInterval(async() => await getData("/getfile/xy"), 3000)`. You just have to make you that the it still need to be `async await`.

Answer (score 0):

response.json() is also an async operation so you need to treat it as a promise like so:

```js
function getData(evt){
    fetch (evt)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json()
    }).then(function(data){
        console.log("DATA",data);
    })
}
```